# Symfony 3.4 - EntityType not working with relational database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

It's my first topic here so sorry if I've done something wrong writing it.

I am writing in Symfony 3.4 and i want to create form that let me chose Category from database and create new Type related to this category. It was working ok before i made relation between databases.

I spent few hours on working out how to make this relation and below are my codes, but i can't find a way how to implement it to my form. I'm still getting errors. Mostly:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO typWydatku (kategoria, grupa) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [null, "Jedzenie_miasto"]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'kategoria' cannot be null
```

Here is the code:

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *      "/dodajTypWydatku",
 *      name="milo_budzet_dodajTypWydatku"
 * )
 * 
 * @Template
 */
public function dodajTypWydatku(Request $Request) {

    $dodajTypWydatku = new Entity\dodajTypWydatku();

    $form = $this->createForm(Type\dodajTypWydatkuType::class, $dodajTypWydatku);

    $form->handleRequest($Request);

    $Session = $this->get('session');

    if($Request->isMethod('POST')) {
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($dodajTypWydatku);
            $em->flush();

            $Session->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Zgłoszenie zostało zapisane');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('milo_budzet_dodajTypWydatku'));

        } else {
            $Session->getFlashBag()->add('danger', 'Popraw błędy formularza');
        }
    }

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

Builder:

```
class dodajTypWydatkuType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder 
            ->add('kategoria', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => dodajKatWydatku::class,
                'choice_label' => 'kategoria'
            ))
            ->add('grupa', formType\TextType::class)
            ->add('Zapisz', formType\SubmitType::class);

}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => dodajTypWydatku::class
    ));
}

}
```

Entity for Type:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="typWydatku")
 */
class dodajTypWydatku {

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * 
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private $kategoria;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * 
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private $grupa;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="dodajKatWydatku", inversedBy="grupy")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="kategoria", referencedColumnName="id_kat")
 */
private $dodajKatWydatku;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set kategoria
 *
 * @param integer $kategoria
 *
 * @return dodajTypWydatku
 */
public function setKategoria($kategoria)
{
    $this->kategoria = $kategoria;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get kategoria
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getKategoria()
{
    return $this->kategoria;
}

/**
 * Set grupa
 *
 * @param string $grupa
 *
 * @return dodajTypWydatku
 */
public function setGrupa($grupa)
{
    $this->grupa = $grupa;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get grupa
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getGrupa()
{
    return $this->grupa;
}

/**
 * Set dodajKatWydatku
 *
 * @param \MiloBudzetBundle\Entity\dodajKatWydatku $dodajKatWydatku
 *
 * @return dodajTypWydatku
 */
public function setDodajKatWydatku(\MiloBudzetBundle\Entity\dodajKatWydatku $dodajKatWydatku)
{
    $this->dodajKatWydatku = $dodajKatWydatku;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dodajKatWydatku
 *
 * @return \MiloBudzetBundle\Entity\dodajKatWydatku
 */
public function getDodajKatWydatku()
{
    return $this->dodajKatWydatku;
}
}
```

Entity for Category:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="katWydatku")
 */
class dodajKatWydatku {

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id_kat;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * 
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private $kategoria;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="dodajTypWydatku", mappedBy="dodajKatWydatku")
 */
private $grupy;


public function __toString() {
    return $this->kategoria;
}



/**
 * Get idKat
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getIdKat()
{
    return $this->id_kat;
}

/**
 * Set kategoria
 *
 * @param string $kategoria
 *
 * @return dodajKatWydatku
 */
public function setKategoria($kategoria)
{
    $this->kategoria = $kategoria;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get kategoria
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getKategoria()
{
    return $this->kategoria;
}
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->grupy = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add grupy
 *
 * @param \MiloBudzetBundle\Entity\dodajTypWydatku $grupy
 *
 * @return dodajKatWydatku
 */
public function addGrupy(\MiloBudzetBundle\Entity\dodajTypWydatku $grupy)
{
    $this->grupy[] = $grupy;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove grupy
 *
 * @param \MiloBudzetBundle\Entity\dodajTypWydatku $grupy
 */
public function removeGrupy(\MiloBudzetBundle\Entity\dodajTypWydatku $grupy)
{
    $this->grupy->removeElement($grupy);
}

/**
 * Get grupy
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getGrupy()
{
    return $this->grupy;
}
}
```

I suppose that it is my stupid mistake but i am new to symfony, i've studied symfony.com references, doctrine docs, stackoverflow and i can't find any sollution. As i said it worked before relating databases, now it's not.

Thanks in advance.

.........................

After making changes from Hanzi there is:

Builder:

```
class dodajTypWydatkuType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder 
            ->add('dodajKatWydatku', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => dodajTypWydatku::class,
                'choice_label' => 'dodajKatWydatku'
            ))
            ->add('grupa', formType\TextType::class)
            ->add('Zapisz', formType\SubmitType::class);

}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => dodajTypWydatku::class
    ));
}

}
```

Entity dodajTypWydatku:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="typWydatku")
*/
class dodajTypWydatku {

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * 
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private $grupa;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="dodajKatWydatku", inversedBy="grupy")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="kategoria", referencedColumnName="id_kat")
 */
private $dodajKatWydatku;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set grupa
 *
 * @param string $grupa
 *
 * @return dodajTypWydatku
 */
public function setGrupa($grupa)
{
    $this->grupa = $grupa;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get grupa
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getGrupa()
{
    return $this->grupa;
}

/**
 * Set dodajKatWydatku
 *
 * @param \MiloBudzetBundle\Entity\dodajKatWydatku $dodajKatWydatku
 *
 * @return dodajTypWydatku
 */
public function setDodajKatWydatku(\MiloBudzetBundle\Entity\dodajKatWydatku $dodajKatWydatku = null)
{
    $this->dodajKatWydatku = $dodajKatWydatku;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dodajKatWydatku
 *
 * @return \MiloBudzetBundle\Entity\dodajKatWydatku
 */
public function getDodajKatWydatku()
{
    return $this->dodajKatWydatku;
}
}
```

But i am still doing something wrong. Now form shows me select "dodaj kat wydatku" but with no options and when i save it there is no error but "kategoria" column in db is null

Answer (score 0):

Your `dodajTypWydatku` entity has *two* properties for the category: `$kategoria` and `$dodajKatWydatku`. That's probably not what you want.

The `$kategoria` property is **not necessary**. You can (and should) remove it. When you have a `ManyToOne` association, Doctrine (Symfony's ORM) will automatically figure out of what type the foreign key column needs to be.[1]

After that, make sure that `dodajTypWydatkuType` adds the `dodajKatWydatku` field and not the (now removed) `kategoria`.

---

[1] You could even remove the `@ORM\JoinColum` line entirely: In that case Doctrine would create a column named `dodajKatWydatku_id` (based on the property name) of type integer.

Comment: Thanks but i am still doing something wrong. I added to my first post code after your changes. Now form shows me select "dodaj kat wydatku" but with no options and when i save it there is no error but "kategoria" column in db is null. I tried to delete "joincolumn" line but doctrine doesn't allow me to update schema after that: "Column name `id` referenced for relation from MiloBudzetBundle\Entity\dodajTypWydatku towards MiloBudzetBundle\Entity\dodajKatWydatku does not exist.". Should i remove everything and start again from beginning without joining these columns?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, yesterday i had to give up because i couldn't do it. Today i looked at it again and bug was in entitytype in my builder. Now it is:

```
$builder 
            ->add('dodajKatWydatku', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => dodajKatWydatku::class,
                'choice_label' => 'kategoria'
            ))
            ->add('grupa', formType\TextType::class)
            ->add('Zapisz', formType\SubmitType::class);
```

And it's working. Thanks and topic to close.